# cURL not sending POST data in PHP

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to make a small API file and for whatever reason the `api.php` file I'm sending cURL data to via POST is not receiving the data. I've looked endlessly on here and Google and can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I've tried various different methods and nothings working.

Here's my code.

client.php:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/listcross2/api.php';

  //var_dump($_POST);
  $rCURL = curl_init();

  $params = array('action' => 'login', 
      'username' => $_POST["username"],
       'password' => $_POST["password"]);

  curl_setopt_array($rCURL, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => "http://www.localhost/listcross2/client.php",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($params)
    )
  );

  $aData = curl_exec($rCURL);

  if(curl_errno($rCURL))
  {
      echo 'error:' . curl_error($rCURL);
  }

  curl_close($rCURL);

  $login_result = json_decode ( $aData, true );

  var_dump($login_result);
```

api.php

```
$value = "An error has occurred within API: ";
var_dump($_POST);

// For POST actions
if (!empty($_POST))
{
  switch($_POST["action"])
  {
    case "login":
        if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["password"]))
          $value = login($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);
        else
          $value = "Missing argument";
        break;
  }
}

exit(json_encode($value));
```

Comment: You've tried various things? Like what?

Comment: Changing any of the CURLOPT params that I've found people trying online to get theirs to work, and using urlencode() to convert the array into a url.

Comment: You don't need to do `http_build_query`. cURLcan accept an array directly and do it itself: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params`.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, what?  Have you checked your access logs to see if any request is being made to api.php?

Comment: Also the http_build_query() doesn't seem to change anything. I'm not getting any errors, and I've debugged via var_dump($_POST) on the api.php page. cURL is calling and returning the API page successfully, however $_POST is NULL when it gets there.

Comment: Do you have the code to the page you are posting to?  I tested your code and it works.  That is, I created a page called api.php and var_dump() the POST array.

Comment: I updated the Q with some of the api.php page. It just calls a function about, where I've commented everything out and left an echo. the var_dump just returns NULL though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I submit to the API page, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function login() in /var/www/playground/api.php on line 13
```

If you define a function called login(), you will no longer get this error.  Also, this code:

```
exit(json_encode($value));
```

results in a null value because you are passing it an invalid argument.  If you pass json_encode() an array you will no longer get the null value returned from this function.  A simple example of the login function:

```
function login($username, $password) {
    return array("username"=>$username, "password"=>$password);
}
```

Comment: While there is a good chance that there's a problem with the OP's `login()` function, `json_encode()` should be able to handle more than just arrays as arguments. From the doc for [json_encode](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php): "PHP implements a superset of JSON - it will also encode and decode scalar types and NULL"

Comment: json_encode has worked with strings earlier, and I just now commented out my login function to just return "works!". client.php still receives NULL (now it's not even returning my error message). This is nuts.

Comment: Patrick, you are correct that it doesn't need to be an array but in terms of the question, the $value variable is null because the function login() is not defined.  I have error_reporting on so the value I get is: Fatal error: Call to undefined function login() in /var/www/playground/api.php on line 12

Comment: @jmeanor "now it's not even returning my error message" What error message? You didn't previously mention that you were getting an error message.

Comment: jmeanor, you need to print the results in the client.php page.  Add this after you define $aData: var_dump($aData);

Comment: Hold the phone! That worked, so I'm assuming json_decode() is villain   here?! Hallelujah! Any idea why json_decode() makes this jenky?

Comment: @jmeanor Where are you using `json_decode()`? I'm not seeing it in the code provided in your post. It reeeeally helps when you provide the code that's actually being run, not just what you think is relevant.

Comment: Sorry, I had a `$login_result = json_decode ( $aData, true );` and var_dump'd it after `curl_close()` . It's just that I got this code from a tutorial and it worked before I modified it to my own use, so I didn't think that was the culprit. Now I know better how to ask my Qs in the future!

Comment: Patrick, I think he meant to say json_encode().  @jmeanor, I don't know for sure if you could say json_encode() is the villian.  It may have been retuning null because you have error reporting turned off and since you did not define the function, what was passed to json_encode() was null or maybe an empty string.  I suspect if you put everything back to the way it was but define the function login() and have it return something you will probably get a response back now that you are printing the results from the API page.

Comment: Oh, never mind, I guess he was referring to json_decode.

Comment: Sorry about that guys, next time I'll just post the full pages. Didn't want it to overwhelm anyone. ;) 

But yeah, I don't know why json decode breaks it?

Comment: My guess (can't really say for sure though) is that `json_decode` isn't able to properly decode the combination of your `var_dump($_POST)` and `json_encode($value)`. I think if you removed the `var_dump` (in api.php), the `json_decode` would work fine.

Comment: That would make sense. I can now play around with it better knowing where to start. Thanks so much guys, I really appreciate it. I've also edited the OP for future readers. :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could contribute to this problem.